# What assumptions are needed to prove that $(ab)c=b(ac)$ implies commutativity & associativity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, noncommutative-algebra

The question is in the title: I would like to know what extra assumptions (if any) are needed for the following derivation that $(a\cdot b)\cdot c=b\cdot(a\cdot c)$  implies commutativity, i.e. $a\cdot b=b\cdot a$, and associativity, i.e. $(a\cdot b)\cdot c=a\cdot (b\cdot c)$.

If I assume the existence of an identity satisfying $a\cdot1=a$ for all $a$ in consideration, then
$$a\cdot b=(a\cdot b)\cdot 1=b\cdot(a\cdot 1)=b\cdot a,$$
so we have commutativity, and given commutativity, we get
$$(a\cdot b)\cdot c=(b\cdot a)\cdot c=a\cdot(b\cdot c),$$
which is associativity.

Are there any structures with no identity element such that $(a\cdot b)\cdot c=b\cdot(a\cdot c)$ for all $a,b,c$, but the operation is not commutative? Can other axioms be used in place of an identity (like, say, a cancellation law $a\cdot c=b\cdot c\implies a=b$)?

Comment: Cancellation doesn't suffice (look at free algebras of the desired type).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I am not familiar with free algebras. What counterexample do you have in mind?

Answer (score 4):

To expand on Martin Bradenburg’s comment : define recursively a
Carneiro expression on $\lbrace a,b \rbrace$ as follows :

1) $a$ and $b$ are themselves Carneiro expressions.

2) If $x$ and $y$ are Carneiro expressions, then $A(x,y)$ is a Carneiro
expression.

3) Any Carneiro expression can be obtained by applying operations
1 and 2 a finite number of times.

Thus, $A(A(A(a,b),a),A(A(a,a),A(b,b)))$ is an example of a Carneiro 
expression. Denote by $C(a,b)$ the set of all Carneiro expressions
on $\lbrace a,b \rbrace$. There is a unique map $d : C(a,b) \to {\mathbb N}$,
such that $d(a)=d(b)=1$ and $d(A(x,y))=1+{\sf max}(d(x),d(y))$ for any
$x,y\in C(a,b)$ : we call  $d(w)$ the depth of $w$, for a Carneiro expression
$w$.

Say that two Carneiro expressions $w_1$ and $w_2$ are elementarily equivalent if 
there are Carneiros expressions $x,y,z$ such that when we replace
$A(A(x,y),z)$ by $A(y,A(x,z))$ somewhere in the expansion of $w_1$ (or $w_2$),
then we obtain $w_2$ ($w_1$). Say that two Carneiro expressions $w_1$ and
$w_2$ are equivalent if there is a finite sequence starting with
$w_1$ and ending with $w_2$, such that each term in the sequence is 
elementarily equivalent to the next one. This is an equivalence relation, and
we will denote it by $\sim$.

Say that a Carneiro expression is reduced if if contains no subexpression of
the form $A(A(...,...),...)$. By induction on $d(w)$, any Carneiro expression
is equivalent to a unique reduced Carneiro expression, that we denote by
$r(w)$.

Let $R(a,b)$ denote the set of reduced Carneiro expressions on $\lbrace a,b \rbrace$.
Define a binary operation $*$ on $R(a,b)$ by $x*y=r(A(x,y))$ for $x,y\in R(a,b)$.

Then, by construction, this binary operation satisfies your axiom $(ab)c=a(bc)$, 
also satisfies cancellation, but is not commutative
(indeed $a*b \neq b*a$) nor associative (indeed $(a*b)*a$ and $a*(b*a)$ are not equal,
since the first one computes to $A(b,A(a,a))$ and the other computes to $A(a,A(b,a))$. )

Comment: I like this construction. It's not very easy to describe, but it is as straightforward as you could be in constructing a structure satisfying the axiom and with no other nontrivial relations on it (I assume this is why they call it a free algebra). It's a bit strange seeing my name on a structure, though. ;) It's not obvious to me that $R(a,b)$ is cancellative, though. Also, it seems like you didn't use the actual form of the axiom anywhere, except at the end with specific counterexamples. What goes wrong if you try to mimic this procedure on more complicated axioms on more variables?

Comment: $l$ is more a depth than a length, isn't it?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen corrected, thanks

Comment: @MarioCarneiro To check that $*$ is cancellative, say that an element $w$ is regular iff $w*x=w*y \Rightarrow x=y$. Then, show by induction on $d(w)$ (what else?) that every element is regular.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro : “What goes wrong ...?” A rather vague question. The construction is very universal. If you want to know more about it, there’s http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-77487-9/page/1 for example.

Answer (score 3):

Consider matrices with even entries modulo $8$. Any product of three such matrices is zero, but we do not have commutativity.